# Alexa Skill - define the pronunciation of a custom slot example

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I've created a skill with an intent containing a custom slot.

I've defined the custom slot and have added various examples.

One of the examples is a branch name which is not pronounced correctly by Alexa.

Is there a way to define the pronunciation of a custom slot example?

**For example, can we change the pronunciation of *backpack* (if it were a brand name)?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you can do is change the spelling of the word to better match the pronunciation that you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a bit more what Tom said, all you can do to help Alexa understand what Alexa *hears* in slots as shown in your example is provide additional spellings.

To help what Alexa *says* though, you can use SSML such as the "say-as" tag.